# Adjusting keyboard shortcuts on Windows

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-vista

How to change default shortcuts?
For example, I want to try Caps+S instead of Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) is probably what you want.  There are some [instructions for remapping keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

You might also be interested in [Ctrl2Cap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897578.aspx)

Comment: I try to do: +CapsLock::CapsLock CapsLock & a::^c CapsLock & s::^v but i'm getting an error. The general idea is Ctrl+C to become Caps+A and Ctrl+V to become Caps+S.